# Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) doesn't update page data

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I have Page_load method like this:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Load Content
        LoadContent();

        return;
        }
     // some code here
}
```

And I use `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)` at the end of methods to prevent re-post actions cased by page refrashing. When I run my app from source code that works well (debug or run mode), but when I publish the app (even on the same machine) page data (which loads on LoadContent) is not updated on updated page (but re-post actions is prevented).

Please, could anyone tell me why it happens?

**ADDED:**

There is `LoadContent()` method:

```
    // firstly I get an supervisedGroups list TIBCO iProcess Engine via .NET vendor library, and then:

    if (supervisedGroups != null)
    {
        rptSupervisedGroups.DataSource = supervisedGroups; // rpt.. is Repeater
        rptSupervisedGroups.DataBind();
    }
```

**ADDED:**

Method where Response.Redirect are used:

```
private void removeFromGroup(string strGroupName)
{
  using(SqlConnection con = DBHelper.GetNewConnection())
  {
      con.Open();
      // here comes query to DB     
  }

  // Reload Page
  Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Comment: What kind of data are you updating, and how? Show us the code for that. And where do you call Response.Redirect?

Comment: maybe have to do with the cache of the page on the client side. If you press shift+reload are they updated ?

Comment: @Aristos the data updated even when I simply press F5, but not on Response.Redirect

Comment: @Alexander I have added methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, but the problem was in vedor library that gives me the data. Question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to solve this cache issue.

One is to give instructions to the browser to not cache this page, for example on page load you run:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-4));
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

But a better solution is to add a random number at the end of the url when you make the redirect, or even better add the new id from the data that you have insert, eg:

```
Response.Redirect("samepage.aspx?newid=" + NewId);
```

that way the page will forced to be readed again, and you still have the cache functionality.

Comment: It's frustrating, but it doesn't work for me. I also have tried add HTML tags to disable page cashing - totally no effect.

Comment: @mike_grinin Use the second way, to add a random number at the end, when you make redirect. This is work for sure.

Comment: I discover problem is in the vendor library I use to get my data. Anyway, thank you a lot, your solutions is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your page is cached. Try to hit shift-f5 to check the content. You can make all redirect urls unique to prevent the browser showing a cached page. Or disable caching for the specific page.

Comment: It seems like it is, but disabling page cashing didn't help. I can't undersand why in that case pressing F5 update content.